# Extracting random times from a series of days in R

Tags: r, random, gps

I have a dataset of GPS fixes (latitudes and longitudes) recorded up to a maximum of 5 times per day at set times (6am, 9am, 11am 2pm and 6pm) each day over a 2 year period. I need to randomly extract 1 time per day as a random sample. How do I do this? Some days no GPS fixes were recorded, other days fewer than 5 GPS fixes were recorded so I need to tell R to randomly extract a GPS fix from each day available day regardless of whether there are 5 fixes to select from. Please help!
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please share some or all of your data using `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`.  The answer to your question will depend on how your data is structured.  Also, you'll find you get much better answers if you share what you have tried so far and why it isn't working rather than just asking for code...

Comment: Really difficult to help without more details on your data (is your date in one column, or split across two, etc.).

Comment: The headers of the data are:

Comment: Sorry I was vague, Im very new to R and help. The data are in 4 columns titled: Date, Time, Lat, Long. I have tried If:Else with a loop but I am confused as to how to tell R to select a random time if there are not 5 choices....

Comment: Hi user3294473. If you are new to R and SO, then I would suggest you to follow others' comments _exactly_ (especially the up-voted ones). Justin suggested to ``dput(head(yourdata, 20))``, so why don't you do that and copy'n'paste the output into your question?